# How to code Jon Skeet's Singleton in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, singleton

On Jon's [site](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) he has thisvery elegantly designed singleton in C# that looks like this:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

I was wondering how one would code the equivalent in C++? I have this but I am not sure if it actually has the same functionality as the one from Jon. (BTW this is just a Friday exercise, not needed for anything particular).

```
class Nested;

class Singleton
{
public:
  Singleton() {;}
  static Singleton& Instance() { return Nested::instance(); }

  class Nested
  { 
  public:
    Nested() {;}
    static Singleton& instance() { static Singleton inst; return inst; }
  };
};

...


Singleton S = Singleton::Instance();
```

Comment: Shouldn't excercises be posted on, I dunno, Monday? Why Friday? <strike>I'd think people had something to do on the weekends other than more work</strike>

Comment: Are you looking for native C++ or C++/CLI? I believe the type initialization rules are entirely different for native C++, so I wouldn't expect the same trick to work. Just for the record, this wasn't my own idea - it was pinched from someone else, although I can't remember who :)

Comment: you may also want to hide the constructor, destructor, copy & assignment operators.

Comment: Uh oh - if Jon Skeet can't code Jon Skeet's Singleton what can the rest of us hope for???

Comment: I don't know C# so perhaps you could explain why this is better than the standard C++ singleton method.

Comment: @paxdiablo: In C#, that would be a thread-safe, lazy loaded singleton. I can't speak for what the standard C++ method is though.

Comment: C++ < C++0x has no understanding of threads, so looking for a standard thread safe anything in C++ is a vain mission

Comment: Any discussions of singletons in C++ should at least mention the extensive treatment of policy-driven singleton implementations in Alexandrescu's _Modern C++ Design_

Comment: And a better exercise would be to figure out how to *avoid* using singletons in a given piece of code ;)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This technique was introduced by University of Maryland Computer Science researcher Bill Pugh and has been in use in Java circles for a long time. I think what I see here is a C# variant of Bill's original Java implementation. It does not make sense in a C++ context as the current C++ standard is agnostic on parallelism. The whole idea is based on the language guarantee that the inner class will be loaded only at the instance of first use, in a thread safe manner. This does not apply to C++. (Also see this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh) entry)

Answer (score 9):

You'll find a great discussion of how to implement a singleton, along with thread-safety in C++ in this paper.

http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Comment: +1 for mentioning this very good article on the topic by Meyers and Alexandrescu.

Comment: Alexandrescu also has a whole chapter on implementing singletons in his book "Modern C++ Design".  The content is probably similar.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, inheritable Singleton behaviour is not possible in C++ or Java, (or at least it wasn't on earlier versions of JDK).  This is a C# specific trick.  Your subclasses will have to explicitly implement the protocol.

Comment: Am I missing something?  I don't think inheritance is entering the picture even in the C# example.

Comment: It would definitely work in Java - that's where I originally got the idea from.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, the OP gave the impression he was after a generic behaviour.  I remember trying to make an inheritable singleton in an early JDK and finding out that Java could not do it; IIRC trad C++ won't either, although you could probably do it with templates.  Now I look at the article again it's not specifically mentioned, so maybe he's just looking at how to implement a Singeton.  The GOF book might have an example in C++.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells: Alexandrescu's "Modern C++ Design" has (as was mentioned elsewhere) treated the subject extensively. Read up on that if you want to know how to do this in C++ generically.